# How to programatically unapply EF Core migration in C# code?

Tags: c#, orm, entity-framework-core, relational-database

It is possible to run EF Core migrations programatically.

```
dbContext.Database.Migrate();
```

Is it possible to revert applied migrations also programatically??
I am looking for smth like this:

```
dbContext.Database.Migrate(0);
```

Thanks for any help in advance.